# What is the solution for MySQL with Delphi XE2?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2, zeos

Zeos Lib still doesn't work for Delphi XE2.
Anybody knows a free component set to deal with MySQL as good as Zeos/Interbase components?

Comment: the components that comes with delphi-xe2 are not on my plans.

Comment: Asking "what is the best" is subjective (asking for opinion), and is not proper here. Please edit your question title to word it differently. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with ADO or dbexpress?

Comment: They did not came configured. I can't open the remote connection with them.

Comment: All the database components need to be configured.

Comment: here is a video on how to set up a a dbexpress connection http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xd0dot_dbexpress-database-access-component_webcam

Comment: @CristianVasuica, I am not that stupid! I have configured all the `TSQLConnection` but I get a "Access Violation" in module `dbxmys30.dll` and that is the point of the question. I just could not get the right libraries...

Comment: Finally ZeosLib came compatible with XE3. Nevermind about XE2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This year 2013 Zeos Database Library is now compatible with XE2 and XE3.
I recomend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use free [FireDAC](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/firedac) if use RADStudio.
FireDAC enables native high-speed direct access from Delphi and C++Builder to InterBase, SQLite, **MySQL**, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Anywhere, Advantage DB, Firebird, Access, Informix, DataSnap and more.